# Get nested relationships dynamically in Apex

Tags: apex, relationships, dynamic-soql

I am building a dynamic SOQL from a JSON file. As of now, I am able to build SOQL for direct parent and direct child objects dynamically. However, I am stuck at a complex/deep relationship.

```
E.g. object->Parent->child->so on. 
  or object->Child->parent->so on.
```

I am okay with 2/3 level relationship(not expecting too deep). Is there way to achieve it dynamically(other than creating a recursive function, I am avoiding since I need to put some conditions on SOQL call, hence it will hard to keep track of conditions,which needs to be applied on that final(nested) object).

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide your current SOQL and explain a bit more what you want to achieve? Do you want to get the child objects or a dynamic list of standard/custom field to query? Do you have had a look on sub queries like https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm?

Comment: Cdr- Opportunity, Account and Contacts object. Opportunity is the center object for me. As of now, I am able to access account object(as it is parent object) . But in this case, Contact is not directly accessible with Opportunity(but from account it is accessible, since it is child of Account). I am aware of querying parent/child objects however finding solution for 2-3 level relationships dynamically.Since I will not be knowing which object is related to which of sub-object present in given JSON

Comment: So is the overall problem that your JSON provides (say) two object names and you have to dynamically find a relationship path between them, possibly through a junction object?

Comment: right. I need to verify some records, so need to find related records only. Therefore need to find relationship(through any related object).